# Hibernate - Logic in a generate method of PooledOptimizer

Tags: hibernate, optimization

Latest PooledOptimizer.java is here: 
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/PooledOptimizer.java

What is the logic behind this line of code in the generate method?

> generationState.hiValue = generationState.value; 
>   generationState.value = generationState.hiValue.copy().subtract( incrementSize - 1 );

Basically, generationState.value contains a sequence value from a DB sequence and a default value of incrementSize is 50.  So, why does it subtract 49 from the sequence value?

Because of this, I am getting unique constraint exception when I persist a newly created entity object.

Thanks,